# VLC crashed when trying to play video

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, video, vlc

I'm trying to play video on my Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine under VirtualBox using `apt-get`'s VLC and I get the following error:

```
$ vlc video.mp4 
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
[0000563941115630] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and

```
$ lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
$ vainfo 
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
$ vdpauinfo 
display: :0   screen: 0
Error creating VDPAU device: 23
```

VideoLAN [Forum Link](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=148280)